# Are most of the verbs in Kaddish in reflexive form?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, kaddish

The beginning of Kaddish has the words יתגדל ויתקדש - I know that there is a debate whether these words are Hebrew or Aramaic. Regardless, it looks that these words are in the *hitpa'el* form (I'm unfamiliar with Aramaic grammar, but, I assume that it has a *hitpa'el* similar to Hebrew.)

If, in fact it is *hitpa'el*, it is reflexive, meaning that G-d is applying greatness and holiness to himself. That doesn't seem to make sense. So, what format are these as well as the other verbs after יהא שמיא רבא , having similar format?

Comment: DanF, I think that in Aramaic those reflexive forms serve as regular passives too, i.e., hitpa'el forms are the ordinary way to express a passive sense.

Comment: @paquda That was my thinking. If that were the case, you assume that these words are Aramit. If so, then, perhaps, those using the Hebrew pronunciation are incorrect, unless this is passive in Hebrew as well. E.g. for passive, I would think the word should be, "nivrach
 and "nigdal". Then, again, my dikduk on this may be way off.

Comment: [Yechezkel 38:23](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.38.23)

Comment: @DanF, I wouldn't be able to contribute anything regarding the disagreement over whether the first words are Hebrew or Aramaic. I just meant that, for Aramaic words, this form is not necessarily reflexive, it's usually just a common passive.

Comment: @DanF you write  "nivrach and "nigdal". perhaps Ybbarech and Yggadel is more appropried